# GWT Project on Apache Tomcat: A child container failed during start

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, gwt

I recently added another servlet to my GWT project. After deplyoing it to tomcat, I am getting an error. When I run it in dev. mode the servlet container is working as intended.

EDIT: It should be added that tomcat fails to start due to the error.

catalina.2014-11-26 log:

```
26-Nov-2014 08:20:53.930 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> buysmarter/download in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3100)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1372)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1176)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5095)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>buySmarterServiceImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>dk.buysmarter.gwt.buysmarter.server.BuySmarterServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>buySmarterServiceImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/buysmarter/buysmarterservice</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>dk.buysmarter.gwt.buysmarter.server.DownloadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>buysmarter/download</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I have configured tomcat to Tomcat server.xml to:

```
<Context path="" docBase="war">
     <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
     <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
<Context path="ROOT" docBase="ROOT">
     <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
     <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

Comment: Isn't it ```/buysmarter/download``` instead of ```buysmarter/download``` in servlet mapping of ```DownloadServlet```

Comment: it should'nt be no. It works that way in dev mode

Comment: If I add /buysmarter/download, it will open url.com//buysmarter/download

Comment: Please check this link for valid `url-patterns` http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/

Comment: I changed web.xml to <url-pattern>/buysmarter/download</url-pattern>.
Still seeing the same error

Comment: I am sorry. It did not compile with the corrections made in web.xml. You were right. Works with "/". Both dev.mode and deployed.
Thx alot